# How come edge loop select does not work?

Tags: selection-tools

I try an Edge loop select in the following object. But Blender 2.79 does not select anything, are there any hidden parameters which can influence edge loop select?

(I try this from the Select menu in Edit mode)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop selection doesn't work with triangular topology, because at an intersection, it can't determine which path to choose.

You can convert the topology to quads with the Tris To Quads function (select all the faces then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>).

Comment: Sorry not working, see updated post above. IMHO the algorithm always should decide based on least arc difference which way to go, the challenge keeps the same for quad based geometry.

Comment: Based on what i see in your second screenshot, it *should* work. Maybe you've got some duplicates (try W/Remove doubles). Consider uploading your file if you can.

Comment: It is working now on some edges but not the whole loop, maybe the arc tolerance is very low.

Comment: Oh, I see, there are still some tri type faces in the converted. So it really must made sure all adjacencies are quad faces at least.

Comment: There is no *arc tolerance*, this tool is based solely on topology (in a mathematical meaning : what is connected to what), not on position. Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7202140/10972299

Comment: If it's possible to convert to quads, then loop select, then why can't the algorithm use the same (convert to quads) in the background and try to emulate the behavior non-destructively. I think that is the expected behavior,